# Update child passed into stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Hi I have a stateful widget called `BobButton()` which basically does an animation where the button bobs up and down when pressed.

> BobButton animates the child widget with a Bobbing effect (It is Stateful)

I pass a child into the BobButton like so

```
BobButton( //Statefulwidget
  child: Widget(
    color: color,
    controller: animationController,
  )
)
```

Some of these widgets have their own animations or have variables that change in the parent widgets state. For example I might call:

```
setState({
  color = Colors.pink
});
```

or

```
animationController.forward()
```

However the widget does not update as the child has already been passed into the stateful widget BobButton.

What should I do to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Widget` override the method

```dart
@override
didUpdateWidget(Widget oldWidget) {
  super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  if (widget.color != oldWidget.color) {
    setState(() {
      //  states variables if neccessary
    });
  }
}
```

`AnimationController` is a `Listenable` so you may add a listener. Or try to check a `value` change in `didUpdateWidget` method as mentioned above.